# Replacing Street abbreviations

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I am working with SQL Server and am trying to replace the abbreviations of some of certain streets into its full name.

For example, turning Dr to Drive, St to Street, etc.

I do not want to flat out match the wildcard  `'%Dr'` and replace it with 'Drive' because there might be some street names that contain Dr.

For example, I wrote this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ssn, first_name, last_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN ADDRESS1 LIKE '%DR.%'
            THEN REPLACE(UPPER(ADDRESS1), 'DR.', 'DRIVE')
        WHEN ADDRESS1 LIKE '% Dr%'
            THEN REPLACE(UPPER(ADDRESS1 ), 'DR', 'DRIVE')
        ELSE UPPER(ADDRESS1)
    END AS fullAddress,
FROM 
    table1
```

I am using all instances of Dr, Dr., Drive, etc, however one of the addresses are:

```
Address | 
1111 Driftwood Ave
```

And if I use the above code, it would turn 'Driftwood' into 'Driveftwood' and that is not my goal. How do I get it to change only when its 'Dr' and nothing else using a pattern match

Comment: Tip: _don't_ use SQL for this. SQL's text-processing features are abysmal. MS SQL Server doesn't even support proper Regular Expressions.

Comment: This will turn into an endless nightmare, just don't do it.  But in your specific example, your second test is missing the period - ` THEN REPLACE(UPPER(ADDRESS1 ), 'DR', 'DRIVE')`.

Comment: You can use an address cleaning service for that, or do it by hand. Assuming that there is no road named "Dr. Jones Drive" may cause problems.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding a space to the end of the text then do a series of nested replaces including the spaces at the beginning and end of each search string. Finally trim the extra space that was added. If you only have a few permutations this should work fine or you could use a series of statements instead of the nested "replace" statements.

```
;with CTE as
(
Select 1 as Ord, '123 Driftwood Dr.'as Address
union
Select 2, '123 Driftwood Dr'
union
Select 3, '123 Driftwood Dr.'
union
Select 4, '123 Driftwood Ave.'
union
Select 5, '123 Driftwood Ave'
union
Select 6, '123 Driftwood Avenue'
)

SELECT RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(Address + ' '),' DR. ', ' DRIVE '),' DR ',' DRIVE '), ' AVE. ', ' AVENUE '), ' AVE ', ' AVENUE ')) as fullAddress from cte
ORDER by ord
```